# NString shows NSDate is 000 instead of Actual Date in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I have application in which i am using NSDate and saving it in NSString but NSString store 000.000 like this here is the code which i am using

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];

NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString*content_AddedTime=str;

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] init];
post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&catalogID=%@&content_AddedTime=%@&organizationCode=%@",userId,catalogID,content_AddedTime,organizationCode];
```

Comment: provide more code with log

Comment: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];` try.

Comment: Double check your format string. The time part is wrong.

Comment: this code will work absolutely fine. please share some more code that is creating problem.

Comment: @SuryantSharma i am posting this to server may be due to that it is not working i am adding that code

Comment: updated code please check

Comment: @user2240329 check my answer. Your dateFormat is wrong it should be `HH-mm-ss` instead of `HH:MM:SS`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to **Log** the NSString.There is no issue with your code.

```
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString*content_AddedTime=str;

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSLog(@"%@",content_AddedTime);
```

**OutPut:**

```
2013-07-30 12:07:67
2013-07-30 12:07:67
```

Comment: @Ramshad, Strangely I get null when trying this here : http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php. And I know this code should work fine. Probably compiler issues maybe ?

Comment: please try to NSLog your "post" variable in Xcode.It should work.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because MM is for month! It should be `HH-mm-ss` instead of `HH:MM:SS`!

Comment: @user2545330 his answer is not wrong. The OP did not ask why minutes are not displayed correctly but why he gets null as a result. (But you are correct that using MM makes no sense)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH-mm-ss"];
```

or you can use:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM/dd/yyyy"];//set ur format
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

 NSString *str= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```